# Pricing tiers for creating a "Service Bus" that will be used as an end point while developing remote event receivers

Tags: azure, remote-event-receiver, service-bus, azure-service-bus, service-endpoint

I want to create some remote event receivers for our sharepoint online sites, and to be able to debug/test the code i need to create a service bus inside Azure, to be used as an endpoint for our remote event recievers. now when i wanted to create a new Service Bus, i got those pricing tiers (Basic,Standard, Premium), as follow:-

[image]

so i am not sure which pricing tier best fit for creating a Service Bus that will be used only to debug/test our remote event receivers? and what are the factors which affect the Pricing tier?

Second question, if i create a new service bus, will we be paid for this upon creation? or we will be paid upon using the service bus for debugging/testing the remote event receivers (per request/duration)?

Thanks